# dynamically determine the value of a column in Hive

Tags: hive

I would like to determine the value of a column in a Hive table by some statement.

e.g., the column is `age`:

`if(some condition are satisfied) the value is 30, otherwise, the value is 10`

so after inserting all the rows, the age of rows which the statement is satisfied are 30 while other rows are 10.

I'm using query like:

`insert overwrite table test_table
select
 A.age
from
(select 
  IF(condition, 30, 10) as age
from some_other_table
) A;`

But the if statement seems only works for true and false. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `condition` should indeed return a boolean value, but you can construct requirements of arbitrary complexity using the [relational](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-RelationalOperators) and [logical](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-LogicalOperators) operators.

If, for instance, you want all males taller than 160cm to be assigned age 30 and all other age 10, you could do the following.

```
select if(sex = "M" AND height >= 160, 30, 10) as age 
from some_other_table
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `select A from (output of another select)` this looks somewhat ambiguous.
Better, you can try like this :

```
insert overwrite table test_table 
        (select IF(condition, 30, 10) as age from some_other_table )
```

where condition should be like this :

```
select IF(height >=170 and gender="male", 30, 10) as age from some_other_table
```

Hope, it helps you.